# Is there a thread safe JacksonJsonObjectReader class in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

If I use Sprint-Batch to read the Json file without specifying `taskExecutor` it works fine, but with `taskExecutor` specified it can't read properly. Wrapping with `SynchronizedItemStreamReader` can solve the problem of thread safety, but it does not work with `JacksonJsonObjectReader`. So I want to know if there is a thread-safe `JacksonJsonObjectReader` class to use

Answer (score 1):

The typical usage of the `JacksonJsonObjectReader` is to use it as a delegate in a `JsonItemReader`. So if you wrap the `JsonItemReader` in a `SynchornizedItemStreamItemReader`, there is no need to synchronize the object reader (since the entire `read` method will be synchronized).

Now if you want to use the `JacksonJsonObjectReader` outside of this setup, you need to synhronize it yourself. This class is not thread safe.